# Factoring out a variable from an unknown multivariable function

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, mathematical-physics

I have a data set that follows the behavior of a function f that depends on a lot of different variables. Let's call two of those variables $a$ and $b$. The specific behavior I'm interested in is $f(a)$ with the influence of b factored out. So I plotted out $f(b)$ and found that it varies depending on another variable, $c$. Fortunately I only care about a handful of discrete c values, so solving for $f(b$) at each of these c values is satisfactory. I found that at a certain $c$, $f(b) = \ln(Ab^3+Bb^2+Cb+D)$ (where I have the specific coefficient values available to me).

I'm not certain how to proceed from here. My intuition tells that simply diving $ \ln (Ab^3+Bb^2+Cb+D)$ out of $f(a)$ at a specific c has the possibility of doing more than just factoring out the b influence. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: This is too vague for anyone to be able to help you. How $b$ can be "factored out" depends on how $b$ is "factored in". If your function were $F(a, b) = g(a)f(b)$, then dividing by $f(b)$ would indeed be the solution. But if the function is $F(a, b) = g(a) + f(b)$, then dividing would be inappropriate. For more complex fornulations, the very concept of the function with "$b$ factored out" is not sensible. You can fix various values of $b$ and see the corresponding function of $a$, but the form of function changes for different values of $b$.

Comment: You're right, I forgot to mention that $F(a,b)=g(a)f(b)F(a,b)=g(a)f(b) $ is something I can assume. In that case it seems it would make since to simply divide out f(b) right?

Comment: Yes. if you know $f(b)$, then you can divide by it to get the function of $a$.